# Help please, I cant work out this equation

Tags: gdp

. In 2012, the imaginary nation of Platland had a population of 10,000 and real
GDP of 42,000,000. During the year its real GDP per person grew by about
1.94%. Which of the following sets of growth rates is consistent with this growth
in real GDP per person?
a. 3% population growth and 4% real GDP growth
b. 3% population growth and 5% real GDP growth
c. 6% population growth and 4% real GDP growth
d. 6% population growth and 5% real GDP growth

Answer (score 1):

$$\ GDP\;Per\;Capita = \frac{GDP}{Population} $$

From this, we know that any growth in GDP Per Capita can be described as follows:

$$\ \frac{\Delta GDP}{\Delta Population} \times 100\% = GDP\;Per\;Capita\;Growth\;\%$$

For example, in case **B** : 
3% Population Growth and 5% Real GDP Growth:

$$\  GDP\;Per\;Capita\;Growth\;\% = \frac{1.05}{1.03} \times 100\% = 101.94\%$$

Which, thus, has a growth of 1.94% and is the answer to your example.